# cmake cross-compile QT6 for QNX fails detecting QNX libraries

Tags: qt, cmake, cross-compiling, qnx

I followed https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/building-qt-for-qnx.html to cross-compile QT 6.2.2 for QNX710 aarch64le on Windows, but doubt that I'm doing it right.

It seems the parameters for QNX are not picked up correctly. It can't find target includes and target libraries.

QNX is installed to my User folder in qnx710.

My toolchain file:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME QNX)

set(arch gcc_ntoaarch64le)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER qcc)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET ${arch})
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER q++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_TARGET ${arch})

set(CMAKE_SYSROOT $ENV{QNX_TARGET})
```

The cmake configuration call (from C:\Work\External\qt_build):

```
cmake -GNinja -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Work\qnx.cmake -DQT_HOST_PATH=C:\Qt\6.2.2\mingw_64 -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Qt-6.2.2 C:\Qt\6.2.2\Src
```

Console output:

```
Checking dependencies of 'qtbase'
Checking dependencies of 'qtshadertools'
Checking dependencies of 'qtsvg'
Checking dependencies of 'qtimageformats'
Checking dependencies of 'qtdeclarative'
Checking dependencies of 'qt3d'
Checking dependencies of 'qt5compat'
Checking dependencies of 'qtactiveqt'
Checking dependencies of 'qtmultimedia'
Checking dependencies of 'qtcharts'
Checking dependencies of 'qtcoap'
Checking dependencies of 'qtconnectivity'
Checking dependencies of 'qtdatavis3d'
Checking dependencies of 'qttools'
Checking dependencies of 'qtdoc'
Checking dependencies of 'qtlottie'
Checking dependencies of 'qtmqtt'
Checking dependencies of 'qtnetworkauth'
Checking dependencies of 'qtopcua'
Checking dependencies of 'qtserialport'
Checking dependencies of 'qtpositioning'
Checking dependencies of 'qtquicktimeline'
Checking dependencies of 'qtquick3d'
Checking dependencies of 'qtremoteobjects'
Checking dependencies of 'qtscxml'
Checking dependencies of 'qtsensors'
Checking dependencies of 'qtserialbus'
Checking dependencies of 'qttranslations'
Checking dependencies of 'qtvirtualkeyboard'
Checking dependencies of 'qtwayland'
Checking dependencies of 'qtwebsockets'
Checking dependencies of 'qtwebchannel'
Checking dependencies of 'qtwebengine'
Checking dependencies of 'qtwebview'
Configuring 'qtbase'
-- Check for feature set changes
    'qtwebengine_build' is changed from OFF to ON
    'qtwebengine_core_build' is changed from OFF to ON
    'qtwebengine_widgets_build' is changed from OFF to ON
    'qtwebengine_quick_build' is changed from OFF to ON
CMake Warning at qtbase/cmake/QtSetup.cmake:265 (message):
  Re-configuring in existing build folder.  Some features will be
  re-evaluated automatically.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/cmake/QtBuildInternals/QtBuildInternalsConfig.cmake:229 (include)
  qtbase/cmake/QtBuildInternals/QtBuildInternalsConfig.cmake:372 (qt_build_internals_set_up_private_api)
  qtbase/CMakeLists.txt:91 (qt_build_repo_begin)


-- Building architecture extraction project with the following CMake arguments:
    -DCMAKE_OBJCOPY=C:/Qt/Tools/mingw900_64/bin/objcopy.exe
    -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=C:\Work\qnx.nto.toolchain.cmake
    -DCMAKE_C_STANDARD=11
    -DCMAKE_CXX_STANDARD=17
    -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:STRING=C:/Qt/6.2.2/Src/qtbase/cmake/platforms
-- Extracting architecture info from C:/Work/External/qt_build/qtbase/config.tests/arch/architecture_test.
-- CMAKE_VERSION: "3.22.0"
-- CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM: "Windows-10.0.19044"
-- CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_NAME: "Windows"
-- CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_VERSION: "10.0.19044"
-- CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR: "AMD64"
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM: "QNX"
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME: "QNX"
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION: ""
-- CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR: ""
-- CMAKE_CROSSCOMPILING: "TRUE"
-- CMAKE_C_COMPILER: "C:/Users/Werner.pirkl/qnx710/host/win64/x86_64/usr/bin/qcc.exe" (8.3.0)
-- CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER: "C:/Users/Werner.pirkl/qnx710/host/win64/x86_64/usr/bin/q++.exe" (8.3.0)
-- Could NOT find ZSTD: Found unsuitable version "", but required is at least "1.3" (found ZSTD_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND)
-- Could NOT find WrapDBus1 (missing: DBus1_LIBRARY DBus1_INCLUDE_DIR WrapDBus1_FOUND) (Required is at least version "1.2")
-- Could NOT find Backtrace (missing: Backtrace_LIBRARY)
-- Could NOT find double-conversion (missing: double-conversion_DIR)
-- Could NOT find WrapDoubleConversion (missing: WrapDoubleConversion_FOUND)
-- Could NOT find GLIB2 (missing: GLIB2_LIBRARIES GTHREAD2_LIBRARIES GLIB2_INCLUDE_DIRS)
-- Found the following ICU libraries:
--   i18n (required)
--   uc (required)
--   data (required)
-- Failed to find all ICU components (missing: ICU_LIBRARY) (found version "67.1")
-- Could NOT find Libb2 (missing: LIBB2_LIBRARY LIBB2_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find LTTngUST (missing: LTTNGUST_LIBRARIES LTTNGUST_INCLUDE_DIRS)
-- Could NOT find WrapSystemPCRE2 (missing: PCRE2_LIBRARIES PCRE2_INCLUDE_DIRS __pcre2_found) (Required is at least version "10.20")
-- Could NOT find PPS (missing: PPS_LIBRARY)
-- Could NOT find Slog2 (missing: Slog2_LIBRARY)
-- Could NOT find WrapBrotli (missing: BrotliDec_FOUND BrotliEnc_FOUND BrotliCommon_FOUND)
-- Could NOT find GSSAPI (missing: GSSAPI_LIBRARIES GSSAPI_INCLUDE_DIRS)
-- Could NOT find Libdrm (missing: Libdrm_LIBRARY)
-- Could NOT find EGL (missing: HAVE_EGL EGL_LIBRARY) (found version "1.5")
-- Could NOT find gbm (missing: gbm_LIBRARY gbm_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find Libinput (missing: Libinput_LIBRARY Libinput_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find md4c (missing: md4c_DIR)
-- Could NOT find OpenGL (missing: OPENGL_opengl_LIBRARY OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find WrapOpenGL (missing: WrapOpenGL_FOUND)
-- Could NOT find EGL (missing: HAVE_EGL EGL_LIBRARY) (found version "1.5")
-- Could NOT find GLESv2 (missing: GLESv2_LIBRARY HAVE_GLESv2 HAVE_GLESv2)
-- Could NOT find WrapVulkanHeaders (missing: Vulkan_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Searching for tool 'Qt6::moc' in package Qt6CoreTools.
-- Qt6::moc was found at C:/Qt/6.2.2/mingw_64/./bin/moc.exe using package Qt6CoreTools.
-- Tool 'Qt6::rcc' was found at C:/Qt/6.2.2/mingw_64/./bin/rcc.exe.
-- Tool 'Qt6::tracegen' was found at C:/Qt/6.2.2/mingw_64/./bin/tracegen.exe.
-- Tool 'Qt6::cmake_automoc_parser' was found at C:/Qt/6.2.2/mingw_64/./bin/cmake_automoc_parser.exe.
-- Using Qt bundled PCRE2.
-- Using source syncqt found at: C:/Qt/6.2.2/Src/qtbase/libexec/syncqt.pl
-- Running syncqt for module: 'QtCore'
-- Could NOT find Backtrace (missing: Backtrace_LIBRARY)
-- Could NOT find double-conversion (missing: double-conversion_DIR)
-- Could NOT find WrapDoubleConversion (missing: WrapDoubleConversion_FOUND)
-- Could NOT find GLIB2 (missing: GLIB2_LIBRARIES GTHREAD2_LIBRARIES GLIB2_INCLUDE_DIRS)
-- Found the following ICU libraries:
--   i18n (required)
--   uc (required)
--   data (required)
-- Failed to find all ICU components (missing: ICU_LIBRARY) (found version "67.1")
-- Could NOT find Libb2 (missing: LIBB2_LIBRARY LIBB2_INCLUDE_DIR)
-- Could NOT find LTTngUST (missing: LTTNGUST_LIBRARIES LTTNGUST_INCLUDE_DIRS)
-- Could NOT find WrapSystemPCRE2 (missing: PCRE2_LIBRARIES PCRE2_INCLUDE_DIRS __pcre2_found) (Required is at least version "10.20")
-- Could NOT find PPS (missing: PPS_LIBRARY)
-- Could NOT find Slog2 (missing: Slog2_LIBRARY)
CMake Warning at qtbase/cmake/QtRpathHelpers.cmake:26 (message):
  No known RPATH_REL_BASE for target platform.
```

```
Configure summary:

Building for: qnx-aarch64le-qcc (arm64, CPU features: neon)
Compiler: rim_qcc 8.3.0
Build options:
  Mode ................................... release
  Optimize release build for size ........ no
  Fully optimize release builds (-O3) .... no
  Building shared libraries .............. yes
  Using C standard ....................... C11
  Using C++ standard ..................... C++17
  Using ccache ........................... no
  Relocatable ............................ yes
  Using precompiled headers .............. yes
  Using LTCG ............................. no
  Target compiler supports:
    NEON ................................. yes
  Sanitizers:
    Addresses ............................ no
    Threads .............................. no
    Memory ............................... no
    Fuzzer (instrumentation only) ........ no
    Undefined ............................ no
  Build parts ............................ libs
Qt modules and options:
  Qt Concurrent .......................... yes
  Qt D-Bus ............................... yes
  Qt D-Bus directly linked to libdbus .... no
  Qt Gui ................................. yes
  Qt Network ............................. yes
  Qt Sql ................................. yes
  Qt Testlib ............................. yes
  Qt Widgets ............................. yes
  Qt Xml ................................. yes
Support enabled for:
  Using pkg-config ....................... no
  udev ................................... no
  Using system zlib ...................... yes
  Zstandard support ...................... no
Qt Core:
  DoubleConversion ....................... yes
    Using system DoubleConversion ........ no
  GLib ................................... no
  ICU .................................... no
  Using system libb2 ..................... no
  Built-in copy of the MIME database ..... yes
  Tracing backend ........................ <none>
  Logging backends:
    journald ............................. no
    syslog ............................... no
    slog2 ................................ no
  PPS .................................... no
  PCRE2 .................................. yes
    Using system PCRE2 ................... no
Qt Sql:
  SQL item models ........................ yes
Qt Network:
  getifaddrs() ........................... no
  IPv6 ifname ............................ no
  libproxy ............................... no
  OpenSSL ................................ yes
    Qt directly linked to OpenSSL ........ no
  OpenSSL 1.1 ............................ yes
  DTLS ................................... yes
  OCSP-stapling .......................... yes
  SCTP ................................... no
  Use system proxies ..................... yes
  GSSAPI ................................. no
  Brotli Decompression Support ........... no
Qt Gui:
  Accessibility .......................... yes
  FreeType ............................... yes
    Using system FreeType ................ yes
  HarfBuzz ............................... yes
    Using system HarfBuzz ................ yes
  Fontconfig ............................. yes
  Image formats:
    GIF .................................. yes
    ICO .................................. yes
    JPEG ................................. yes
      Using system libjpeg ............... yes
    PNG .................................. yes
      Using system libpng ................ yes
  Text formats:
    HtmlParser ........................... yes
    CssParser ............................ yes
    OdfWriter ............................ yes
    MarkdownReader ....................... yes
      Using system libmd4c ............... no
    MarkdownWriter ....................... yes
  EGL .................................... no
  OpenVG ................................. no
  OpenGL:
    Desktop OpenGL ....................... no
    OpenGL ES 2.0 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.0 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.1 ........................ no
    OpenGL ES 3.2 ........................ no
  Vulkan ................................. no
  Session Management ..................... yes
Features used by QPA backends:
  evdev .................................. no
  libinput ............................... no
  INTEGRITY HID .......................... no
  mtdev .................................. no
  tslib .................................. no
  xkbcommon .............................. no
  X11 specific:
    XLib ................................. no
    XCB Xlib ............................. no
    EGL on X11 ........................... no
    xkbcommon-x11 ........................ no
QPA backends:
  DirectFB ............................... no
  EGLFS .................................. no
  EGLFS details:
    EGLFS OpenWFD ........................ no
    EGLFS i.Mx6 .......................... no
    EGLFS i.Mx6 Wayland .................. no
    EGLFS RCAR ........................... no
    EGLFS EGLDevice ...................... no
    EGLFS GBM ............................ no
    EGLFS VSP2 ........................... no
    EGLFS Mali ........................... no
    EGLFS Raspberry Pi ................... no
    EGLFS X11 ............................ no
  LinuxFB ................................ no
  VNC .................................... yes
  QNX:
    lgmon ................................ no
    IMF .................................. no
  XCB:
    Using system-provided xcb-xinput ..... no
    Native painting (experimental) ....... no
    GL integrations:
      GLX Plugin ......................... no
        XCB GLX .......................... no
      EGL-X11 Plugin ..................... no
  Windows:
    Direct 2D ............................ no
    Direct 2D 1.1 ........................ no
    DirectWrite .......................... no
    DirectWrite 3 ........................ no
Qt Widgets:
  GTK+ ................................... no
  Styles ................................. Fusion Windows
Qt Testlib:
  Tester for item models ................. yes
Qt PrintSupport:
  CUPS ................................... no
Qt Sql Drivers:
  DB2 (IBM) .............................. no
  InterBase .............................. no
  MySql .................................. no
  OCI (Oracle) ........................... no
  ODBC ................................... no
  PostgreSQL ............................. yes
  SQLite ................................. yes
    Using system provided SQLite ......... no
Qt 5 Compatibility Libraries:
  iconv .................................. no
Qt QML:
  QML network support .................... yes
  QML debugging and profiling support .... yes
  QML just-in-time compiler .............. yes
  QML sequence object .................... yes
  QML XML http request ................... yes
  QML Locale ............................. yes
Qt QML Models:
  QML list model ......................... yes
  QML delegate model ..................... yes
Qt Quick:
  AnimatedImage item ..................... yes
  Canvas item ............................ yes
  Support for Qt Quick Designer .......... yes
  Flipable item .......................... yes
  GridView item .......................... yes
  ListView item .......................... yes
  TableView item ......................... yes
  Path support ........................... yes
  PathView item .......................... yes
  Positioner items ....................... yes
  Repeater item .......................... yes
  ShaderEffect item ...................... yes
  Sprite item ............................ yes
Qt Tools:
  Qt Assistant ........................... yes
  QDoc ................................... no
  Clang-based lupdate parser ............. no
  Qt Designer ............................ yes
  Qt Distance Field Generator ............ yes
  kmap2qmap .............................. yes
  Qt Linguist ............................ yes
  Mac Deployment Tool .................... no
  pixeltool .............................. yes
  qdbus .................................. yes
  qev .................................... yes
  Qt Attributions Scanner ................ yes
  qtdiag ................................. yes
  qtpaths ................................ yes
  qtplugininfo ........................... yes
  Windows deployment tool ................ no
Qt Quick Templates 2:
  Hover support .......................... yes
  Multi-touch support .................... yes
Qt Quick Controls 2:
  Styles ................................. Basic Fusion Imagine Material Universal macOS Windows

WARNING: QDoc will not be compiled, probably because libclang could not be located. This means that you cannot build the Qt documentation.
Either set CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or LLVM_INSTALL_DIR to the location of your llvm installation.
On Linux systems, you may be able to install libclang by installing the libclang-dev or libclang-devel package, depending on your distribution.
On macOS, you can use Homebrew's llvm package.
You will also need to set the FEATURE_clang CMake variable to ON to re-evaluate this check.
WARNING: Clang-based lupdate parser will not be available. LLVM and Clang C++ libraries have not been found.
You will need to set the FEATURE_clangcpp CMake variable to ON to re-evaluate this check.

ERROR: The OpenGL functionality tests failed!  You might need to modify the include and library search paths by editing QMAKE_INCDIR_OPENGL[_ES2], QMAKE_LIBDIR_OPENGL[_ES2] and QMAKE_LIBS_OPENGL[_ES2] in the mkspec for your platform.

CMake Error at qtbase/cmake/QtBuildInformation.cmake:72 (message):
  Check the configuration messages for an error that has occurred.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  qtbase/cmake/QtBuildInformation.cmake:10 (qt_configure_print_summary)
  CMakeLists.txt:87 (qt_print_feature_summary)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Work/External/qt_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Work/External/qt_build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

CMakeOutput.log:

```
The target system is: QNX -  - 
The host system is: Windows - 10.0.19044 - AMD64
Compiling the CXX compiler identification source file "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/Users/Werner.pirkl/qnx710/host/win64/x86_64/usr/bin/q++.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
0


Compilation of the CXX compiler identification source "CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp" produced "a.out"

The CXX compiler identification is GNU, found in "C:/Work/External/qt_build/CMakeFiles/3.22.0/CompilerIdCXX/a.out"

Compiling the C compiler identification source file "CMakeCCompilerId.c" succeeded.
Compiler: C:/Users/Werner.pirkl/qnx710/host/win64/x86_64/usr/bin/qcc.exe 
Build flags: 
Id flags:  

The output was:
0
```

Comment: on Linux this works just fine...